Weight Painting Does Not Showing Affected Areas, Using Rigify
Weight painting does not showing after using rigify. I don't see any changes or affected weight areas yet they still bend and I cannot change them. Rig was set through rigify and automatic weight parenting. I seen some similar thread mentioning its a old bug or some sort of driver issue, yet some saying it worked on different machines just fine. At some point I managed to reverse paint it, somehow I painted all the areas (through the vertex painting I believe) that were affected red except the one that I need and it worked, but I'm not sure how I did it and I believe its not how it supposed to be regardless.
Here File;


Problem was solved by below mentioned post. I'm leaving this comment for those who new like me and need a good guide for proper wight painting and understanding, since after solving this issue, DEF. bones could still warp mesh in unexpected ways even after seemingly proper paint. Here is the video guide on how to paint individual bones clear and fast, all credit and thanks goes to author of said video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCCnsfwQ7Ww&list=PL0GmFLtVI2Hed1YzkaEaZ-lwUw6ixwFUD&index=8

Rigify Uses DEF-* bones to manipulate meshes. By default, collection with def-* bones are hidden. You can enable them by activating this eye icon here:

Here is how it looks like, then you edit weight paint:

Other bones are not usable for deformation because they are disabled:


Thanks,it worked, not sure what this Deform toggle supposed to mean though, is this related to meta rig?. Thanks again also for a pictures, I'm very much new so it helps a lot to see where everything is like that.

Deform is a toggle for bones that enables mesh deformation when the armature modifier is used. So if you have bones that are used to control other bones, you usually want to disable them so they are skipped in the automatic weighting process. Rigify automatically sets the deform for DEF bones and disables for others
